# Node.js readline.on('line', fn()) doesn't see newlines

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, readline

I was trying to write a simple terminal IRC client using readline and net.

Sending commands using `client.write()` works perfectly fine, except when I do it within `readline.on('line' (cb) => cbstuff)` and I am not sure why.

I have two ideas about a possible problem and no clue how to fix any of them:

My first guess is that I have to change something about `rl.createInterface()` to work with client instead of stin/stdout.

My second suspicion is that readline never sees a carriage return because the `\n` or `\r\n` gets filtered/escaped somewhere. On the other hand sending `\r\n` directly in `client.write()` works as expected for multi line messages.

Here's my code:

```
const net = require('net');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const host = 'irc.freenode.net';
const port = 6666;
const client = new net.Socket();

rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

client.connect(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`CONNECTED TO: ${host}:${port}\n`);
    client.write('USER foo bar batz boo\r\nNICK nodetest123\r\n');
    client.write('JOIN #testchan123\r\n');

    rl.on('line', cmd => client.write(cmd));
    // rl.prompt(); doesn't help
});

client.on('data', data => {
    console.log(`DATA: ${data}`);
    fs.appendFile("log.txt", data, err => {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
    });
});

client.on('error', error => console.log(error));
client.on('close', () => console.log('Connection closed'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is probably in `client.write(cmd)`, I think it should be `client.write(cmd + '\r\n')`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it and I feel incredibly stupid now, I even said I suspected there was no carriage return sent and for some reason I never thought of sending it manually and expected readline to do it for me.